# Accelorometer values without gravity

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, gravity

so this seems to be a fairly seen question but I still don't entirely get the answers I've seen. Currently I'm programming on an arduino, and I have an accelorometer that I want to get the magnitude (Don't care about orientation too much) of acceleration without gravity effecting it.

I'm sampling this at 20Hz currently, so I'm not sure if this will effect my sample rate, but so far I've seen examples from [Android help pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) I was wondering if this would be okay to use on the arduino (ADXL345 acceloromter). The other thing is I don't understand it entirely.

```
          final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
```

From this code I'm assuming this:
Alpha is a sort of chosen value (at the moment I'm just rolling with that number)
event.values[0] is going to be for example my x axis acceleration data.
But then I don't get what gravity[0] is? Basically I'm looking at it like this

Total gravity = alpha * previous gravity +(1-alpha) * current acceleration value

acceleration with gravity = current acceleration value - total gravity

My project essentially is done by having an accelerometer in a ball and someone is holding it and moving it around and I just want to see the different accelerations on it without gravity.

Comment: You might want to ask the underlying question about separating gravity and acceleration in a physics forum. I'm not sure it is possible unless you know the ball's orientation relative to the earth.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I've looked for this answer around a few places, and some people tell me its possible by just filtering, other people tell me its not possible at all without knowing orientation. Its been a really mixed bag of answers to be honest.